# Let $E$ be the set of points for which $f(x)>g(x)$, where $f$ and $g$ are cont. funcs. Show $E$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be two continuous functions from $(X,d)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $E = \{x \in X:f(x)>g(x)\}$. Prove that $E$ is an open subset of $X$.

My attempt:

Let $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$. Then $h(x)$ is clearly continuous and $E = \{x \in X: h(x)>0\}.$ Define $F = \{h(x) \in \mathbb{R}: h(x)>0\}$. Then $E = h^{-1}(F)$, where $h^{-1}$ denotes the inverse image of a set in $\mathbb{R}$ to a set in $(X,d)$ under the function $h$.

Is it true that $E = h^{-1}(F)$? I have a proof prepared if this is true, but I am not sure about this detail. I know that for a given subset $E$ in the domain that $E \subset f^{-1}(f(E))$ and this is what I am a little worried about.

Comment: It is true that $E=h^{-1}(F)$; but actually you don't want to define $F$ at all (because it depends a lot on which values in $\Bbb R$ are in the range of $h$). Instead just note that $E = h^{-1}((0,\infty))$. (It doesn't matter whether all values in $(0,\infty)$ are hit or not - this is still most convenient.)

Answer (score 3):

If $f,g$ , are continuous, then so is $h=f-g$. Then E is the inverse image of the open set $(0, \infty)$ under the continuous map h .